# Starting an executable from a relative path

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am building a relocatable directory with several executables in it (among other files). The tree looks like this:

```
root
  +-- bin
      +-- app 1.exe
      +-- app 2.exe
  +-- config
  +-- log
  app 1.???
  app 2.???
```

Notice the `???` on the files in the root? I want those to start the apps in `bin`, but use `root` as working directory. I tried several things:

- Shortcuts: Didn't work, as they do not allow relative paths.
- BAT file: Didn't work, as it always starts a command line window.
- VBS file: Cannot get it to work.

About the VBS file, this is what I have now:

```
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run(".\bin\app 1.exe")`
```

but this gives me a `"cannot find path"` error on line 2.

Any idea how to do this? (I come from Linux, where stuff like this is dead easy using a shell script or softlink).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
oShell.Run("\.bin\app1.exe")
```

to

```
oShell.Run ".\bin\app1.exe"
```

`\.bin` looks for `.bin` in `CurrentDrive:\`. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) for the removal of the ().

With quotes:

```
oShell.Run """.\bin\app1.exe"""
```

(VBScript's escape for " is "")

Comment: No luck. The dot though, was a simple typo. Losing the parentheses had no effect.

Comment: I must say I have spaces in my `.exe`'s name.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `Run()`, you can use the `CurrentDirectory` property of the `Shell` object to set you current working directory:

```
strExeName = "app 1.exe"

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.CurrentDirectory = "bin"
oShell.Run Chr(34) & strExeName & Chr(34)
```

Edit:

@Ekkehard's solution should work, too. You just need to encase any paths with spaces in double quotes. Use `"""" & strPath & """"` or `Chr(34)`, as shown above.

Comment: Almost. I want the CWD to be `root` though, not `bin`.

Comment: If you want to launch a file in `bin`, you can change the `CurrentDirectory` temporarily, or reference it using a relative path, as @Ekkehard has shown.

Comment: Using @Ekkehard's solution combined with the `Chr(34)` made it work. Who to accept now ...? ;-).

Comment: Accept @Ekkehard's since the path escaping wasn't part of your original question.